# How to refer to own property of an interface in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to refer to an own property in an interface.

Let's consider this example:

```
type PizzaType = "pepperoni" | "margherita" | "cheese";

interface Pizza {
    bakeTime: number;
    size: number;
}

interface PizzaService {
    availablePizzaTypes: Record<PizzaType, Pizza>;
    calculatePrice: (type: PizzaType) => number;
}
```

Take a look at `PizzaService.calculatePrice`. We know the type must be `PizzaType`. This works fine.

But let's imagine, we don't know the `PizzaType` and we only want to refer to the `availablePizzaTypes`. Something like this:

```
interface AnonymousPizzaService {
    availablePizzaTypes: Record<string, Pizza>;
    calculatePrice: (type: << How to refer to `availablePizzaTypes`? >>) => number;
}
```

I want to use something along the lines `type: (keyof availablePizzaTypes)` but that doesn't work.

So how do I do something like that in Typescript?

**EDIT**
Here's a simpler example:

```
interface Pizza {
    name: string;
    // When `name` is e.g "pepperoni", names can only be "['pepperoni']".
    names: this["name"][];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are going to need a type parameter to `AnonymousPizzaService` to capture the actual pizza types supported:

```
type PizzaType = "pepperoni" | "margherita" | "cheese";
interface AnonymousPizzaService<T extends PizzaType> {
    availablePizzaTypes: Record<T, Pizza>;
    calculatePrice: (type: T) => number;
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACglgLwQQwCrmgXigIkmSAJwHsA7OHKAH1wFtlCBzACwkLmGUppwGNWIAZwg4A3AFgAUHFLA2AM2S9o8JMigBvKVB1QARsgDWEVHFoQAXFFIBXWnrYTJuqIMSXrdh4ScBfKVIycoSKylAAgqRkILTENoKqKADKbABucMoAPKhQEAAecqQAJoKwiCjokAB8mtq6yKnIcAA2yHrNEIloGIJWAEoQvMSERdkANGVqVU4uvMjNvDatcjDsylYAFKCQVqgAlFCYNbb2jlL+kkA)

Comment: No way to do it without a generic?

Comment: You can access the type of another field with an indec type `AnonymousPizzaService[availablePizzaTypes]` and get the get using `keyof` but if the type of the field is `Record<PizzaType, Pizza>` you will just be getting `PizzaType` back ..

Comment: Oh I'm sorry but I think you misunderstood me. The pizzaType can be anything. It doesn't need to extend from `PizzaType`, that's why it's a `string`.

Comment: @Myzel394 if you want it to have the correct type in the callback, the types have to be known at compile time ..